# Unexpected margin/padding on the right side of my website

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am using vuejs and bootstrap framework for my website; however, there is a white space on the right hand side of the entire website which I do not know how to get rid of. I try to eliminate the margin or padding, but nothing works. Please help.

[Testing website link](http://americandunnage.n55lwi.info/#/)
[image: I got this unexpected margin on my right side of my website.]

Comment: this is not a direct VueJS problem, i thikh its all about your slider.
Try to change your `img` tags into `div` with a background-size: cover; and background-image style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (as mentioned) has nothing to do with VueJs. You seem to have several elements that extend the width. One quick way you can fix that is using this css

```
#app {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```